# Change UIImageView height on scroll

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

I need to resize imageview on scroll and tried some answers in stackoverflow but failed to implement those. Not sure what did I missed, please advice.

```
-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    int scrollY = scrollView.contentOffset.y;
    if (scrollY > 0) {
        _coverImgView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 23 + scrollY, 375, 139 - scrollY);
        _coverImgView.center = _coverImgView.superview.center;
    }
}
```

Sharing current configuration of my UIImageView

[image: Configuration]

Also sharing UI

[image: UX]

Let me know, your suggestions on this.
Expecting UIImageView to reduce height onscroll.

Comment: So what are you expecting it to do and what does it do?

Comment: Expecting it to reduce height of uiimageview on scroll

Comment: Are you using auto layout?

Comment: do not use auto layout and setting frame the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using auto-layout you shouldn't be directly setting the frame of any of your views, you should be changing the layout constraint constants to reposition and size your views and then updating the layout.

So, change the 'top' and 'height' constraints each time the delegate method is called, then `layoutIfNeeded`.

Comment: I am new in ios, can you please guide me how to set top and height?

Comment: What constraints have you added to the view? Any? You need to add some. Have you read a guide about constraints?